# how to change the property value of an object nested in a tree of nodes?

Tags: javascript

Given the following data set, I need to change the value of the leaf property to true of the last nested element.

```
const data = [
    {
        label: "root",
        data: 1,
        expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
        collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            {
                label: "Italy",
                data: 6,
                expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
                collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        label: "Bolognia",
                        data: 8,
                        expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
                        collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
                        expanded: true,
                        children: [],
                        leaf: false, // <-- this need to be true
                    },
                ],
                leaf: false,
            },
        ],
        leaf: false,
    },
];
```

In this case the target is the object

```
{
    label: "Bolognia",
    data: 8,
    expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
    collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
    expanded: true,
    children: [],
    leaf: false,
},
```

This tree will always have this structure, it can be extended or contracted indefinitely.

Having described the above, the expected result is the following

```
const data = [
    {
        label: "root",
        data: 1,
        expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
        collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            {
                label: "Italy",
                data: 6,
                expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
                collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        label: "Bolognia",
                        data: 8,
                        expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
                        collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
                        expanded: true,
                        children: [],
                        leaf: true, // <-- updated
                    },
                ],
                leaf: false,
            },
        ],
        leaf: false,
    },
];
```

I understand it can be achieved using recursion but I can't identify how to do it. Thank you for your advices

**update 1**

I am trying the following to get the target node but I always get *undefined*

```
function tried(data) {
    if (data.children.length === 0) {
        return data;
    }

    tried(data.children[0]);
}

const output = tried(data[0]);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going the right way, just missing the `return` on recursion call

```js
const data = [
  {
    label: 'root',
    data: 1,
    expandedIcon: 'pi pi-folder-open',
    collapsedIcon: 'pi pi-folder',
    expanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Italy',
        data: 6,
        expandedIcon: 'pi pi-folder-open',
        collapsedIcon: 'pi pi-folder',
        expanded: true,
        children: [
          {
            label: 'Bolognia',
            data: 8,
            expandedIcon: 'pi pi-folder-open',
            collapsedIcon: 'pi pi-folder',
            expanded: true,
            children: [],
            leaf: false,
          },
        ],
        leaf: false,
      },
    ],
    leaf: false,
  },
];

const getLastNestedElement = (data) => {
  if (data.children.length === 0) {
    return data;
  }

  return getLastNestedElement(data.children[0]); // you need to return
};

const lastNestedElement = getLastNestedElement(data[0]);
lastNestedElement.leaf = true;

console.log(JSON.stringify(lastNestedElement, null, 2));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks, it's already late here and I'm out of ideas. I appreciate a lot your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursion function

```js
const data = [{
  label: "root",
  data: 1,
  expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
  collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
  expanded: true,
  children: [{
    label: "Italy",
    data: 6,
    expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
    collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
      label: "Bolognia",
      data: 8,
      expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open",
      collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder",
      expanded: true,
      children: [],
      leaf: false, // <-- this need to be true
    }, ],
    leaf: false,
  }, ],
  leaf: false,
}];

function doRecursion(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].children) {
      if (arr[i].children.length > 0) {
        doRecursion(arr[i].children)
      } else {
        arr[i].leaf = true
      }
    }
  }
}

doRecursion(data);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion? Did you mean "Recursion"? :-). All jokes aside, recursion is the process of repeating similar patterns with a larger pattern. So a simple binary tree is a good example of this process:

[image]

At reach branch, we are going down a left path and a right path, cause exponential growth because of the nature of this recursive process. What you will notice is that at some point the tree ends. This is called the *base case*; when there are no more children (*ahah!*), we want to stop the recursion and start the process of slowly currying back up the tree.

In your case we don't have to consider what to do with the multiple different returns since we are going down and heading right back up as a single path.

To set up recursion, I usually start by defining the recursive step. *Let's assume that it works, and it will all fall into place*:

```
function recur(data) {
    
    // return whatever recur gives us:
    return recur(data.children[0]);
}
```

***Note that this initial strategy assumes there is just one child, you will have to update this code if you have multiple values in the `children` array.***

**Okay!** So we have this initial setup here, but I'm sure you're wondering, "wait... this never stops" And you would be right to wonder. That is where our base case comes in! If there are no children elements, we should just return whatever data is (*the lowest object in this big data*) and call it a day:

```
function recur(data) {
    if (!data.length) // if no children
        return data;

    // return whatever recur gives us:
    return recur(data.children[0]);
}
```

This is really your basic definition of recursion, but what we are searching for is how to search for a specific element! That is where we need a search parameter. By "the target is the object ... " I'm going to make an assumption that "Bolognia" is a primary key that won't occur anywhere else. So, now if we're searching for a specific element in here based on our key "Bolognia", we need to add another parameter to our search function that now looks for our primary key:

```
function recur(data, key) {
    if (!data.length) // if no children
        return data.label == key ? data : undefined; // ONLY send data if key == label, otherwise we can send an empty response

    // return whatever recur gives us:
    return recur(data.children[0]);
}
```

*Sooo*, now this function recur will only return us a value if the lowest element has the inputted `key`. Of course, since recursion is so fun and interesting I'm also going to show how you could search for a specific element, so you could add a loop that checks all children elements and finds the occurrence of the element that has a label that matches the key:

```
function recur(data, key) {
    if (!data.length) // if no children
        return data.label == key ? data : undefined; // ONLY send data if key == label, otherwise we can send an empty response

    // loop through all children of data to find occurrence
    // of an element that has a label that matches key:
    let found_data = undefined; // initialize a variable to hold our response
    for (let child_search = 0; child_search < data.children.length; child_search++) {
        // recursively look for data
        found_data = recur(data.children[child_search]);

        if (found_data) // WE FOUND DATA! break
             break;
    }

    // maybe there's data, maybe there's not... let's return:
    return found_data;
}
```

And voila! Given the input to the function `recur(data, "Bolognia");`, your response will be the sub-element that contains that matching label at which point you could just set the response of the `recur` function to a new variable and set leaf to true:

```
let element = recur(data, "Bolognia");
element.leaf = true;
```

You can of course take out the search param and do the above just the same way and that will also work, but it's always fun to have a bit of an endless discussion of recursion!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the expected behavior as follows

```
function tried(data) {
    if (data.children.length === 0) {
        data.leaf = true;

        return;
    }

    tried(data.children[0]);
}
```

If I missed something I will appreciate the feedback